# How to get latency, sample time, bytes and other such variables used in different listeners when using Java Request Sampler

Tags: java, jmeter

I am not able to capture to use the methods of HTTPSamplerResult.

What should i do to get the Sample Time(ms), Bytes, Sent Bytes, Latency, connect time and other parameters.

I am not able to get these details in the Listener : **view Results in Table** and other listeners as well.

Can someone help me with this.
I didn't get the implementation of how to set all the variables.

Below is my code for my java request sampler.

```
public HTTPSampleResult runTest(JavaSamplerContext arg0)
{
    HTTPSampleResult result = new HTTPSampleResult();
    //Below array contains the user id and password that comes with every chirp
    byte[] idpwd = new byte[]{38,85,115,101,114,78,97,109,101,61,101,82,101,103,38,85,115,101,114,80,97,115,115,119,111,114,100,61,97,98,99,49,50,51};

    //below we are converting the hex string coming as parameter to Byte Array.
    byte arr[] = toByteArray(arg0.getParameter("HEX"));
    //Below we are getting the lengths of both the arrays : idpwd & arr
    int aLen = arr.length;
    int bLen = idpwd.length;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //below we are initializing the byte array to contain both our hex string converted to byte array and the id-pwd.
    byte[] actual_Chirp = new byte[aLen+bLen];

    //Below we are concatenating both the arrays.
    //first we are adding the arr to the actual_chirp.
    //then we are adding the idpwd from the alen to blen.
    System.arraycopy(arr, 0, actual_Chirp, 0, aLen);
    System.arraycopy(idpwd, 0, actual_Chirp, aLen, bLen);

    //Here we we actually hit the meter service
    try
    { 

        URL obj = new URL(arg0.getParameter("URL"));
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();

        result.sampleStart();

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        os.write(actual_Chirp);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



        result.sampleEnd();

        result.setContentType(con.getContentType());
        result.setSamplerData(POST_URL);



        System.out.println(con.getContentType());
        System.out.println(result.getHTTPMethod());
        System.out.println(result.getRequestHeaders());
        System.out.println(Hex.encodeHexString(result.getResponseData()));





        result.setSuccessful(true);

        System.out.println(con.getResponseMessage());



    }
    catch(Exception E)
    {
    }

    //

    return result;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing sample label, or maybe more. `HTTPSampleResult` (or `SampleResult` in general) is sort of container for accumulating all the data related to execution. All visualizers or reporters rely only on `SampleResult` for stats, so if they ignored yours, it means you didn't put enough data in it for them to consume. Good reference for you would be a source code for [HTTPHC4Impl.java](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/48484573/). A few things I can spot as missing:

- Label most obviously, this is what is causing your issue most likely

  ```
  result.setSampleLabel("your label");
  ```

  Usually this is set before `result.sampleStart();` and after constructor
- I cannot imagine that this can cause sampler to be ignored, but anyways: usually you are expected to set response code and response message. Here's an example from source code mentioned above:

  ```
  res.setResponseCode(Integer.toString(statusCode));
  res.setResponseMessage(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
  ```
- Also review other fields in that code. For example for HTTP specifically, Method and URL have special properties, which makes them nicely formatted in result

  ```
  result.setHTTPMethod("POST");
  result.setURL(POST_URL);
  ```

Comment: Well, there are many properties that I am not able to set. Or I don't know how to do it. Like getting the latency , bytes , connect time etc... Also there is no proper documentation / procedure online for the same.

Comment: yes, documentation is a big problem when developing new samplers. There's none. Best you can do is to look at source code of existing samples, this is why I linked HTTPHC4Impl.java - closest to what you are doing.